# How to delete a space between a number and a character using r and stringr

Tags: r, regex, replace, stringr

I am using  R and stringr to do some string replacement. My text is like "xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5L xxxxx" or "xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5 L xxxxx".

My question is: how to delete the space between 1.5 and L? or How to add a space between them?

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all(c("xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5L xxxxx", "xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5 L xxxxx"), '(\\d) (\\w)', '\\1\\2')`, or use lookarounds, or just stick to `gsub`

Comment: thanks! it works really well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a single capture group using `sub`

```
sub("(\\d+)\\s+", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5L xxxxx" "xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5L xxxxx"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5L xxxxx" , "xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx 1.5 L xxxxx")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use library(stringi)

```
library(stringi)

text <- "1.5 L"
stri_replace_all(text,"1.5L" ,fixed = "1.5 L" )


[1] "1.5L
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
replacer=function(x)
{
  match_term=str_replace(str_match(x,'(?:[0-9]|\\.)+(?: +)([A-Z])')[,1],' +','')
  return(str_replace(x,'([0-9]|\\.)+( +)([A-Z])',match_term))
}
```